# VLC suddenly not working correctly in Catalina

Tags: vlc

I dont know what happened but all of a sudden, VLC no longer properly works properly for me. While videos do play, they take anywhere from 60seconds to 5 minutes to load and freeze the entire app to the point while loading where if I change my mind, VLC must be Force Quit to close. Playlists do not run properly and you cannot change from screen to playlist without causing the app to seize up on MacOS. Additionally shifting to and from VLC can cause the entire app to lag and freeze.

I've tried DOZENS of files to test if there was a file corruption and they all load eventually but play flawlessly in QT. I have deleted org.videolan.vlc from my ~/Library several times, changed the file cache from 1000 to 60,000 and uninstalled and reinstalled VLC about 3 times but it's the same every time. Nothing seems to work and these suggestions are the only things I can find through search engines on how to fix this problem. I deleted all app data on uninstall and reinstall. I was told that doing these things would cause the program to reset and play normally. It did not and I have run out of ideas.

I just need help with the steps utilizing this application now. I dont know what else to do to fix VLC on my MacOS Catalina. I've run out of options on Google, they all keep suggesting I do the things I listed above. I'm out of ideas. I dont know where else to go. Please help? I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Drop it on [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware) to make sure you actually got everything at uninstall & try again.

Comment: Try it on a freshly created user.